# Groovy Sql.execute() with sql statement as string variable not working

Tags: groovy, groovy-sql

I am trying to execute a sql statement in groovy by passing the statement as a string variable rather than a string literal.  The reason I am using a string variable is because I am reading the sql statement from a file.

For example (assuming sql is a valid Instance of groovy.sql.Sql - which I have verified):

```
sql.execute("insert into table(id) values(1)")
```

Works just fine.

However, the following does not:

```
def str = "insert into table(id) values(1)"
sql.execute(str)
```

The last example just hangs when I run it.  No SQL errors, it just stalls.  I tried putting a println after the execute and it never reaches the println statement.

So, I tried the following variations:

```
sql.execute("$str")
```

and

```
sql.execute("${str}")
```

and even

```
sql.execute("?", [str])
```

for curiosity's sake, but all give the following error:

```
Mar 21, 2013 6:28:16 PM groovy.sql.Sql execute
WARNING: Failed to execute: ? because: Invalid SQL type: sqlKind = 0
Caught: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid SQL type: sqlKind = 0
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid SQL type: sqlKind = 0
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:77)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1010)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1315)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3576)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3677)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1374)
        at runSqlFile.run(runSqlFile.groovy:40)
```

I am admittedly new to groovy, but I can't figure out why a string literal works but the variable will not.  Any help here would be greatly appreciated.  Let me know if more information is needed.

Also, the reason I am grabbing individual sql statements from a file is because I could not find a way to execute an entire .sql file using groovy.  If there is a simple way to do that which I haven't found, that would also solve my problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: sql.execute("$str") will not work, but sql.execute(str) or sql.execute("$str".toString()) should work. I just tried it.

Comment: @Kunal +1 That is strange. Just tried it again with sql.execute(str) , since you mentioned it should work and also tried sql.execute("$str".toString()).  Both work now.  Not sure why the former didn't work earlier.  Thanks for the tip, though!

Comment: Figured out the reason: I had SQL Developer open connected with the same credentials that I was using in my groovy script.  I believe this was the cause of the stalling.  As soon as I closed SQL Developer, the script ran fine.  Thanks for the help, all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured out the reason: I had SQL Developer open connected with the same credentials that I was using in my groovy script. I had executed a few commands in SQL Developer and neglected to commit them, which caused a conflict when running the groovy script.  This was the cause of the stalling. As soon as I committed the changes made in SQL Developer, the script ran fine.

Comment: Not caused by having a connection from SQL developer, but more likely because you had uncommitted transactions in SQL developer which were blocking the groovy script from committing.

Comment: Yes, thank you for clarifying - that was the case. Updated answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this works fine with mySql, so my guess is that it's an issue with the Oracle JDBC driver. I've no experience with it myself, but I understand it's not the most reliable piece of software you can find.

This is a bit of a shot in the dark, but:

```
sql.execute("$str")
sql.execute("${str}")
```

In both these calls, the value passed to `sql.execute` isn't actually a `String` but a `GStringImpl`, which might have something to do with your issue.

About your last example:

```
sql.execute("?", [str])
```

This just isn't valid. `?` will be interpreted as a value, not an SQL statement. What you're doing is passing a string, which happens to contain valid sql. The result if it contained `"foobar"` would be the same.

The only example for which I can't come up with anything is:

```
def str = "insert into table(id) values(1)"
sql.execute(str)
```

Are you sure you're not doing anything to `str` before passing it to `sql.execute`? Can you make sure it doesn't somehow become wrapped in a specialised groovy class such as `GStringImpl` ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I forgot to mention that I also tried `sql.execute(str.toString())` (and `.toString()` with all the other attempts) to try to ensure that it didn't get caught up with the `GStringImpl` issue, but to no avail.  And there are no other lines of code between `def str = "..."` and `sql.execute(str)` so that isn't the issue.